# Kalman filter basic application/learning - Code seems very slow

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, kalman-filter

I have a platform rotating and a single sensor measuring it's position i tried to program a simple kalman filter to smooth the measurements. My measurement runs are between around 10000-15000 datapoints long. The simulation runs over 3 minutes.

I expected the code to be quite faster since kalman is used in real time applications. Also other calculations i did with the measurements don't take nearly as long and are almost  instant. Or is this normal because of the matrix operations?

I mostly used this example as template [Kalman Filter Implementation for Constant Velocity Model (CV) in Python](https://github.com/balzer82/Kalman/blob/master/Kalman-Filter-CV.ipynb?create=1). Below is my code maybe there's possibilities to write it differently to make it faster?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.matrix([[0.0, 0.0]]).T # initial state vector x and x_point

P = np.diag([1.0, 1.0]) #!!! initial uncertainty 

H = np.matrix([[1.0, 0.0]]) # Measurement matrix H 

StD = 20 # Standard deviation of the sensor 

R = StD**2 # Measurment Noise Covariance 

sv = 2 # process noise basically through possible acceleration

I = np.eye(2) # Identity matrix

for n in range(len(df.loc[[name], ['Time Delta']])):
    # Time Update (Prediction)
    # ========================
    # Update A and Q with correct timesteps
    dt = float(df.loc[[name], ['Time Delta']].values[n])

    A = np.matrix([[1.0, dt],
                  [0.0, 1.0]])

    G = np.matrix([dt**2/2,dt]).T #!!! np.matrix([[dt**2/2], [dt]]) # Process Noise

    Q = G*G.T*sv**2    # Process Noise Covariance Q 

    # Project the state ahead
    x = A*x # not used + B*u
    # Project the error covariance ahead
    P = A*P*A.T + Q

    # Measurement Update (Correction)
    # ===============================
    # Compute the Kalman Gain
    S = H*P*H.T + R

    K = (P*H.T) * S**-1 #!!! Use np.linalg.pinv(S) instead of S**-1 if S is a matrix 

    # Update the estimate via z
    Z = df.loc[[name], ['HMC Az Relative']].values[n]
    y = Z - (H*x)                           
    x = x + (K*y)

    # Update the error covariance
    P = (I - (K*H))*P
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Calling the pandas "address" in the for iteration for dt and Z made the code really slow. I created two new variables for the dt and z arrays now my code is pretty much instant.
[PythonSpeedPerformanceTips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) helped me to realize where my problem is. Also [StackEchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would've been a better place to ask this kind of question for anyone who reads this and has a similar problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.matrix([[0.0, 0.0]]).T # initial state vector x and x_point

P = np.diag([1.0, 1.0]) #!!! initial uncertainty 

H = np.matrix([[1.0, 0.0]]) # Measurement matrix H 

StD = 20 # Standard deviation of the sensor 

R = StD**2 # Measurment Noise Covariance 

sv = 2 # process noise basically through possible acceleration

I = np.eye(2) # Identity matrix

timesteps = df.loc[[name], ['Time Delta']].values
measurements = df.loc[[name], ['HMC Az Relative']].values

    for n in range(len(df.loc[[name], ['Time Delta']])):
    # Time Update (Prediction)
    # ========================
    # Update A and Q with correct timesteps
    dt = timesteps[n]

    A = np.matrix([[1.0, dt],
                  [0.0, 1.0]])

    G = np.matrix([dt**2/2,dt]).T #!!! np.matrix([[dt**2/2], [dt]]) # Process Noise

    Q = G*G.T*sv**2    # Process Noise Covariance Q 

    # Project the state ahead
    x = A*x # not used + B*u
    # Project the error covariance ahead
    P = A*P*A.T + Q

    # Measurement Update (Correction)
    # ===============================
    # Compute the Kalman Gain
    S = H*P*H.T + R

    K = (P*H.T) * S**-1 #!!! Use np.linalg.pinv(S) instead of S**-1 if S is a matrix 

    # Update the estimate via z
    Z = measurements[n]
    y = Z - (H*x)                           
    x = x + (K*y)

    # Update the error covariance
    P = (I - (K*H))*P
```